# Why does this barbell use two split barrel washers?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Why does this barbell use two half washers?

For example: see this [link](https://powerliftingtechnique.com/barbell-sleeve-replacement/)

Navigate to the “Taking Apart A Barbell Sleeve” section.
[image]

They use a washer, two half washers, a shim washer, another washer and then retaining rings.

The split washer is not the traditional split washer that acts as a positive locking mechanism.

It looks like [this](https://tippmannarms.com/m4-22-barrel-split-washer/).

My question is this: why did the designers use this type of washer? I do not see the advantage over a normal washer.

Comment: You kind of do not ever use the same term twice to refer to it since are three different terms used, but I assume it's the one second one from the right in the photo since it's the only weird one? I'm wondering if it might ease assembly somehow.

Comment: look at the size of the hole in the split washer ... it is much smaller than the shaft ... there is no way to place the washer onto the shaft if the washer is not split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm looking at a video and I don't have a completely clear view:

[image]

https://youtu.be/zUFIJQqsoQE?t=90

But from what I can see, I think those half-washers are primary load bearing components that hold everything on the shaft in the axial direction, not the retaining rings. That would make sense since retaining rings aren't very strong. Retaining rings are meant to be springy pieces of metal that can be removed which means they are limited in thickness.

From the glimpses I can see, there is a circular groove cut into the central shaft and the half washers sit into that groove from opposite sides. Sliding the sleeve over them keeps them in place by preventing motion in the radial direction. The sleeve must have a lip or shelf at the bottom of the hole inside it that hits the half washers if anything tries to drag the sleeve off the barbell.

Obviously, a full washer that must slide on from the end can't sit snugly in a groove cut into the shaft.

That means they're the most important piece out of everything you listed...I think? But then what stops the sleeve from sliding too deep onto the barbell? It seems like it would need to be the retaining rings but it doesn't seem like they would be strong enough, and obviously the sleeve itself slides back by design when you remove the retaining rings so you can access the half washers.